# Windows 10 can't use linux samba share anymore

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, samba

My windows 10 machine stopped being able to access samba shares on several debian servers. I can connect to them, but as soon as I look at any file or directory I get access denied. Last week it used to work, and nothing has changed in the linux machines. There has been a windows 10 update and I am suspecting that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: what version of samba?  You need a new enough one to support the SMB2 protocol.

Comment: The update basically installed Windows again, you should repeat the procedure, to connect a Windows machine to a samba share.

Comment: I have already rtied unconnecting and reconnecting the shares. No change.

Comment: The version of samba is the newest version

Comment: There any logs that are generated chance?

Comment: Assuming you have samba 4.3.3 maybe you disabled SMB2, or didn't enable it in the smb.conf

Comment: it was working, with no changes on the linux side, and stopped after windows-10 updated.

Comment: 1511 right? "winver" to confirm

Comment: Version 10.0 (Build 10240)